# Image not displaying in production mode

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

Images are not displaying in production mode. It is working fine in the development environment.

For example, image is not displayed for the following code

```
<img alt="" class="img-circle" src="/assets/avatar.jpg">
```

But it works for image_tag

```
<%= image_tag 'avatar.jpg',class:"img-circle", :width=>'29' %>
```

which generates the following html

```
<img class="img-circle" width="29" src="/assets/avatar-cabb5744ce203e3fd174df28be60bfb942d35013b57513680aadda2ba9602762.jpg" alt="Avatar cabb5744ce203e3fd174df28be60bfb942d35013b57513680aadda2ba9602762">
```

Production.rb

```
  config.serve_static_files = false

  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier

  config.assets.compile = false

  config.assets.digest = true
```

The file avatar.jpg is actually available in the assets/images folder.

What is the actual issue here? How do I resolve this?

Comment: Try this `<img alt="" class="img-circle" src="<%= asset_path('avatar.jpg') %>">` instead...

Comment: This works. But i am confused why the url '/assets/avatar.jpg' is not serving the image when the image is actually available in the assets/images folder

Comment: Please check @tadman's answer for the explanation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you need to be using `image_tag` for any assets like that. You can't hard-code the path because they change when you compile those assets and they get hashed.

Rails does a content hash on each static asset to ensure the name is unique for any given revision. This avoids cache busting problems where you need to force people to refresh to get changes and also helps preserve the cache for assets that haven't changed.

The downside is the final name is unpredictable and you need to use `image_tag` to compute it when the application is running in production mode.